# pdb in a client-server application

Tags: python, debugging, asynchronous, networking, pdb

The use case is as follows: I have an application, a TCP server on which clients can connect, send and receive information.  Clients can send little scripts to be run by the server (that's only a small portion of trusted users who have the right to do that).  Notwithstanding the danger of such a situation, I'd like to know how to debug these scripts.  And to offer these users power to debug.  In short, pdb seems like a good match to me.

But still, I'm facing several problems:

- pdb has to not use standard input and output, but the socket connected to the client.  In theory it seems doable, by creating a new Pdb object.
- pdb has to not freeze the entire program, just offer to examine a specific script (probably a string of lines) and run them asynchronously.  Other users shouldn't be frozen.

I've tried to look into the code of the pdb module, but I admit I don't really know whether I can do both things at the same time.

Thanks for your help,